# Scheme expression

Tags: scheme

I'd be really grateful if you explain this question for me. I've been pondering on it for quite some time but couldn't make it out. I'm a self-learner and this is an exercise from MIT' s icampustutor site.

Indicate the type of each of the following expressions. Use the symbols "->" to denote "maps to", for example, the procedure square has type "number->number". Use the following terms to describe primitive types of data: number, boolean, string.

```
1-(> 3 4) 
2-((lambda (x) (* x 2)) 4)
3-(lambda (a b) (+ a (if b 1 0)))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you should at least make a guess for each type, explaining your reasoning.  I'd be willing to comment on that and explain where you were right or wrong.

Comment: For first one i said (number,number)->boolean,
and the second one (number->number)->number but i hvae no idea about the third one

Answer (score 1):

Get help:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version ...
> (> 3 4)
#f
> ((lambda (x) (* x 2)) 4)
8
> (lambda (a b) (+ a (if b 1 0)))
#<procedure>
```

The type of the first expression is a boolean, the type of the second is a number, and the type of the last expression is a procedire.

To see the type of the procedure ask your self what the types of a and b must be.

<type of a> <type of b> -> <type of (+ ...)>

Since + always returns a number, the return type must be a number.

<type of a> <type of b> -> number

Now fill in the types of a and b.